# Does the differential equation $\text{cos}(t)y′+y\text{sin}(t)=(\text{cos}(t))^2$ have a singular point at $t = \pi$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does the differential equation $\text{cos}(t)y′+y\text{sin}(t)=(\text{cos}(t))^2$ have a singular point at $t=\pi$? It is a first order differential equation and I dont know what to do for this. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Divide both sides by $\cos^2 t$ to get that

$$1 = y' \sec t + y \tan t \sec t = (y \sec t)'$$

$$\implies y = t\cos t + C \cos t $$

The differential equation did not have a singular point at $t = \pi$, it would happen at $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Thank you so much